# How to combine data generated in a for loop into a single scatter plot?

Tags: r, for-loop, scatter-plot

I have this code that calculates p-values at certain named markers in a file (object `gts`). The for loop produces the scatter plots for each `trait` that is defined in `pts`.

[image: Scatter plot from loop]

```
pts <- read.csv('data_rqtl_phenotypes.csv',as.is=T)
gts <- read.csv('data_rqtl_genotypes.csv',as.is=T)
gts <- gts[,c(1,grep('2B',gts[1,]))]### use only 1B
gts <- gts[,!apply(gts[2,],1,duplicated)]### remove duplicated
dim(gts)### 93 229
map <- gts[1:2,]### salvage map
gts <- gts[-c(1:2),]
gts[gts=='-'] <- NA
testdfr <- merge(pts,gts,by='id')
testdfr[1:5,1:10]

pdf('SingleMarkerAnalysis_ParW471_2021_10_21.pdf')
for( trait in colnames(pts)[-1])
{
 print(trait)
pValueL <- c()
for(marker in colnames(gts))
{
    model <- try(lm(testdfr[,trait]~testdfr[,marker]))
    {
        if(any("try-error"%in%class(model)))
            print('not enough data for a test')
        else
        {
            modelsum <- summary(model)
            coeffs <- modelsum$coefficient
            print(coeffs)
            pValue=coeffs[grep('[AB]$',row.names(coeffs)),grep('Pr',colnames(coeffs))]
            print(pValue)
            if(length(pValue)>0)
                pValueL[marker] <- pValue
        }
    }
}

plot.default(map[2,names(pValueL)],-sapply(pValueL,log10),main=trait,xlab='Chr 1B [cM]', ylab='-log10(pValue)',ylim=c(0,7))
}
 dev.off()
```

However, I want to take the data produced from each iteration and then plot it on the same scatter plot, so that I can colour each one and see how they compare when on top of each other. I'm not sure how to get the loop to output each iteration to a new object so that they can be plotted together. if anyone knows how this can be done, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: After running the loop, do you get a `pValueL` object with all values from each iteration? Then you can use the `points()` function to add each set of values to the initial plot.

Comment: Ah thanks, that helped. So pValueL only stores the data from one iteration, and then gets replaced after each iteration. I managed to produce the scatterplot I needed by manually defining 'trait' and running only the second for loop for the associated markers from 'for( marker in colnames...etc' and then adding via points. I think if I incorporate the points() function into the full loop, I can get the  plot I want without having to do things manually